# Android gridview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi i have problem with android gridview in fragment. i have search solution but not success, maybe in here i get solved to this problem. Thanks.
My code is:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frontpage, container, false);
        createGridCategory(inflater, view);
        return view;
    }

    public void createGridCategory(LayoutInflater inflater, View container) {
        AdapterView<ListAdapter> itemsGridViewObj = (GridView) container.findViewById(R.id.newsScrollerContent);

        categoryNames = database.getEnabledCategories()[1];
        physicalCategories = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>(categoryNames.length);
        physicalItems = new ItemLayout[categoryNames.length][categoryRowLength]; 

        // loop through adding category views
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryNames.length; i++) {
            RelativeLayout categoryTitleBar = (RelativeLayout) inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_category_item, null);

            categoryTitleBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int id = physicalCategories.indexOf(view);
                    clickHandler.onCategoryClick(categoryNames[id]);
                }
            });

            TextView name = (TextView) categoryTitleBar
                    .findViewById(R.id.categoryTitle);
            name.setText(categoryNames[i]);

            physicalCategories.add(i, categoryTitleBar);
            itemsGridViewObj.addView(categoryTitleBar);
        }
    }
```

Layout in /res/layout/frontpage.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsScroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F5F5F5" >   

   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/newsScrollerContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</ScrollView>
```

layout in /res/layout/list_category_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/categoryTitleBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Title"
        android:textSize="17sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

If i look error in logcat is:

```
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader/com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.ReaderActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1959)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.ReaderActivity.onCreate(ReaderActivity.java:450)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    ... 11 more
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:445)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.fragments.FrontpageFragment.createGridCategory(FrontpageFragment.java:123)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.fragments.FrontpageFragment.onCreateView(FrontpageFragment.java:95)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:845)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1058)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1156)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:270)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
01-09 05:02:20.139: E/AndroidRuntime(10804):    ... 21 more
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Are there more errors in the LogCat?

Comment: Hi Sam thanks for reply, i have update info log. Please read my post again.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `AdapterView<ListAdapter> itemsGridViewObj = (GridView) container.findViewById(R.id.newsScrollerContent);`?

Comment: what? i ask not ******** !!!!!!!! zzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: That's nice, the LogCat clearly shows the problem is with `itemGridViewObj`. If you would like help beyond that you will need to use real words with proper capitalization and punctuation to form coherent sentences.

Comment: In my logcat theren't itemGridViewObj, but if i remove or ignore  itemsGridViewObj.addView(categoryTitleBar); so it's fine, run without force close, but no content, line this itemsGridViewObj.addView(categoryTitleBar); to create title from database.

Comment: The LogCat states: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView   at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:445)` I agree the problem is with `itemGridViewObj`, but in order to understand what you are trying to do you need to answer: "What are you trying to do with this line `AdapterView<ListAdapter> itemsGridViewObj = (GridView) container.findViewById(R.id.newsScrollerContent);`?"

Comment: take the adapter out of the array. if it can take an array of patents? and incorporated into the grid. example title is ("ABC", "DEF","RGD"). without get title from database.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using an unsupported method that throws UnsupportedOperationException. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#addView%28android.view.View%29)

You can override.